# SharePoint 2013 Product catalog Feature

Tags: sharepoint-2013, catalog, cross-site

If we have column in share point List then how these column will be available in "catalog item url fields " while doing "Catalog Settings" for the list.

Answer (score 0):

Only Single line of text type fields, managed metadata type fields and default column ID and Version can be available in the Catalog Item URL Fields.

Please check the type of the columns in your list to confirm that they are in the right types.

I have Created a new column in single line type or managed metadata  (**don't allow multiple value**) type to see if the column would be available.
I don't know somehow previous column is not coming but what i am creating new are all coming.